# read Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP or HTTPS)

Tags: http, url, https

I want to read the protocol the user is on. HTTP or HTTPS and build my url for site 2 on that page accordingly.

Step 1:   `Read the url user is on site 1`  //Could be anything http or https

Step 2:   `Prefix the protocol for site 2 on that site 1 page according. HTTP or HTTPS as per step 1`

FF handles it good. But IE doesn't allow navigation from HTTPS site to HTTP site.

```
   <a href="protocol://site2.com/">Click here for site 2</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn’t allow it? And what’s your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with `String scheme = request.getScheme();` in my JSP

Answer (score 7):

From my jsp, I was able to break an URL into parts. For example, `https://test.com:8080/` would yield:

```js
request.getScheme() = https
request.getServerName() = test.com
request.getServerPort() = 443
```

See [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getProtocol%28%29) for details.

Answer (score 1):

What language are you trying to do it in?

For JavaScript, there's `parent.location.protocol`

For PHP, you can try using `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443` or even `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`

Comment: You can try using `HttpServletRequest.getProtocol()` or `HttpServletRequest.isSecure()`